# Can I give out my e-mail here?

Tags: support, email

Can I give out my e-mail address here, or are users not supposed to do that?

Answer (score 7):

You are welcome to put your email in your profile, but please don't spam the Q & A site.

Comment: This seems to be the closest match to the advice offered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/what-to-do-when-questioner-posts-email-address-for-responses i.e. OK in profile, but not in questions and answers.  I don't think it should be OK in comments either but I have not yet seen that case covered anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

As everyone else has said, you can post your email if you want, but its a good idea to take precautions.

However, if you're asking if you can post your email and request users to email you directly rather than go through the answer system, then no. Your email address will be removed and you'll likely get comments about how bypassing the Q&A system defeats the purpose of the website. Answers should be posted on the site for the benefit of everyone, private help is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

It's never safe to publish your email address on an open web site.  If you want someone to get in touch set up a new temporary address and use that until you're sure you can trust them.  Even if the people on the site are trustworthy there are people out there harvesting every publicly available email address and selling them to the spammers and mass marketers.

Comment: Your email provider probably does the same thing, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to give out your e-mail you can either in a question, answer or better still in your profile.

However, it will be publicly visible and readable by spiders etc. so you might want to make it harder (but not impossible) to work out what it is.

Comment: Meh. Spam filters are remarkably good these days. My email address is everywhere... I use Google hosted mail, I get 500+ spams a day and maybe one every two weeks makes it past the filters. I don't even have to maintain them.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you want to. You should probably keep yourself safe and try to obfuscate it in some way. Use something like myusername [at] whatever *dot* com instead of just saying myusername@whatever.com. It will at least keep the dumbest email scraping bots away.