# Generally bad user and what to do about it?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Sorry if I come off as rude.  I just get annoyed with people like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/730436/vipul-vankadiya

As you can see, he came on SO around 10 days ago, and he's asked 14 questions - not particularly useful questions, mind you, but specific problems that he's having.  This isn't the main problem either.

*`He Writes Every One,, Of His Questions...Like This ,,,Making A Tough Editing...Job.`*  (Okay, enough imitation) In addition, he doesn't seem to recognize that you're NOT supposed to put signatures in your post, but instead he keeps blasting his email in each question like this:

> If You Have Any Sample Project Then Also Send Me On My Mail..
>
> `<snipped>`
>
> Please Help Me...

Overlooking his miserable accept rate of `0%`, this is the kind of user that soaks up stuff from SO and never gives back.

What can be done about these types of people, and this person in particular?

Comment: YES. I've asked this user *several times* to please stop doing this. He or she has consistently ignored me. I say time for a spell in the penalty box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the plus side, clicking through the answers he's received, he doesn't really seem to be getting great responses (not surprisingly) -- doesn't look like anyone's wasting too much time on these questions.

In that vein, given that there's mostly been no response on his part to requests for clarification, details, etc., I think that many of them could be closed as "Not a Real Question: vague/incomplete". A certain number of closings will bring a user to the attention of The System, I believe. Moderator flags are also a good option, but I am not certain that they're warranted in this case*, since "normal" (>3k) users can take care of these questions.

Having said that, I would like to make absolutely clear that I am only advocating closing the questions that are *actually* vague or incomplete, and not simply close-vote-lynching this user.

UPDATE: There are at least two pairs of duplicates in his question history.

*Actually, mod flags [may be warranted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/what-to-do-when-questioner-posts-email-address-for-responses/) for persistent email address posting. I forgot about that part.

Comment: Alright, I voted to close the ones I felt needed to be closed.  Lets hope the system will catch on and deal with this guy. :)

Comment: @sudorm-rf Actually, I'd just flag one of his posts with flag text mentioning what you've posted in the question - I'm pretty sure he'll get suspended

Comment: Yowza, I didn't see that meta question.  That's the same troublesome user.  I'm guessing I'm not the only one that's bothered about this I guess. :)

Comment: @sudo: Huh, I didn't even notice that part. I was just referring to the general rule about posting addresses.

Answer (score 8):

I know there was a post on the SE blog about users that don't give back getting warned then getting suspended for X days.

Actually here it is: [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

One of the reasons:

> The user never gives anything back to
> the community, but only takes.

Comment: I would accept your post as answer, but in this case I don't believe the user can be "taught" new tricks.  Even after repeated warnings he doesn't stop posting his email as a signature, so even after a suspension he probably wouldn't change his ways, or he even might make a new account.

Comment: @sudo: While I empathize with you, I'd like to gently suggest to you that such a determination is not yours to make, but the moderators'.

Comment: @Josh:  Thanks.  I wasn't planning on trying to take matters into my own hands, but I just wanted to get the ball rolling. :)

Comment: @sudo, he did say if the user did not learn the account would eventually be permanently deleted.

Comment: @sudo: Of course, there's not really any more that you can do than posting here and flagging for a moderator; I'm just wary of posse-rousing. :)

Comment: Are we forgetting "member for 10 days" here? How many 10-day users have substantially given something back?

Comment: @Henk: I do appreciate your defense of a new user. It's a matter of opinion, surely (and mine is not the one that counts), but I'd say that 1.5 questions per day, which includes duplicates or "Okay, I copied the answer snippet from my last question, now fix it", no answers, no comments (except one on his own question), and not even a single vote, adds up to a very bad start.

Comment: @Josh, right, and I don't say there should be no feedback. But it takes time to get around SO. I find the quality of the questions the most important. There is no Q/A rate, for good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If the post is bad you can downvote it.  You can also flag it for moderator attention.  My favorite approach is to ignore the question.

Comment: Sure, but if you see a user being *consistently* bad and you want to improve the overall quality of the site, just ignoring it isn't a great option.

Comment: @Anna, in my experience, focusing on the negative aspects of things is not a great option either.  I know that I will spend a finite amount of time on stackoverflow.  It seems to me that reading nonsensical questions or complaining about them is not the best way I can spend that time.  But, to each their own...