# Questions on SO asking us to code.

Tags: discussion, spam

So 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133071/need-a-start-for-building-intrusion-detection-system-in-python?noredirect=1#comment33582853_22133071) 
just got asked on SO. The OP apparently thinks that he can ask us to build a *intrusion detection system* and he'll get replies. Before it was edited, it also had his email asking us to mail him the finished product. As [noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/what-to-do-when-questioner-posts-email-address-for-responses) by [usmcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633094/usmcs) that isn't **The Stack Overflow Way™**

So what should we do under these circumstances? I flagged it for moderator attention, but haven't received a response yet.

Comment: a downvote would be enough and a close vote or flag to vote. It is not so specal that a mod needs to handle that.

Comment: Don't bother the moderator: let the community handle it.

Comment: @rene so just let the question rot? Seems fair enough.

Comment: @devnull yeah it has like -5 now, so that should shut it down.

Comment: And... I cast the final Close Vote on it, so it's now on hold.

Comment: Oh co-incidence or did it get closed due to this post?

Comment: Good going guys :D Justice.

Comment: that post had a brother: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919154/need-a-sample-project-code-for-firewall-development-in-python-java

Comment: @TimSeguine they just keep coming.

Comment: @Tim with 3 significantly downvoted questions I expect that will be the last of them before the big Q-ban

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to flag these for moderator attention - this is the kind of thing the community can manage easily without mods.

Downvote, vote to close and move on.

If you feel the need, you can hop into one of the chatrooms (The Tavern always has some people) and ask for help in getting a speedy closure.

---

One note, seeing as you tagged the question here with the "spam" tag. **Do not** flag such a question as spam. It is not spam - it is simply an unsuitable/bad question. Reserve spam flags for actual spam - someone trying to sell something or advertise instead of asking a question.

Comment: Although this guy was trying to, quite apparently, get us to do his job, probably something he would actually get _paid_ for.

Comment: @Sabyasachi - be that as it may, he isn't trying to sell us something or advertise. This is not spam, however unwelcome it is and shouldn't be flagged as spam.

Comment: `tagged the question "spam"` should be `flagged the question "spam"`. ;)

Comment: @hichris123 - nope. The question **here** on Meta was tagged with the `spam` tag. The actual question the OP was referring to wasn't flagged as spam ;) - clarified answer...

Comment: Oh, okay. Makes more sense, sorry! :P

Comment: @Oded okay got it. That is why I didn't flag it spam in the first place, because I wasn't sure. I figured tagging the meta question as spam wouldn't do any harm.