# Can I give my email id in reply to user comment?

Tags: support

I have a problem here. If some one is asking me for my email id while commenting on a question. Am I supposed to do that?

Please refer comments on: [Create strings from MySQL entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322715/create-strings-from-mysql-entries)

I am asked to provide my mail contact and can I give it in reply?

I refered some questions:

[Can I give out my e-mail here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/can-i-give-out-my-email-here) says I can do it by posting in my profile. But can I reply him here is my question. Is it against rules?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I am asked to provide my mail contact and can i give it in reply?

You *can* give it if you are so inclined, but by no means you *have* to.

It's highly unorthodox to ask for someone's E-Mail address, and often it's to bug you for free one-on-one support. Which you are absolutely not obliged to give.

Comment: i want 2 buy genuin hand bag plz give e mail so i can send offer

Comment: @balpha +1 for the laugh

Comment: And such comment doesn't seem very different from [the original](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGsTf.png), @balpha.

Comment: @balpha to be honest, I find it hard to tell whether you would be a trustworthy business partner for my beautiful, genuine discount handbags. Your use of txtspeak makes me think you could be a joker, or try to rip me off. Appearances are so important

Comment: @Arjan heh. Thanks for the heads up! But you have to give it to him that the glitzy Unicorn *is* kinda cool.

Answer (score 14):

You have a link to your website on your profile http://about.me/mithunsatheesh

And on this page, An Email me Button, your Facebook and twitter...

He shouldn't even ask.

And I think you shoudn't give him.