# Is asking for details by email allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers

Are people allowed to post their email address in an answer, asking for code or possible solutions on any of the Stack Exchange sites?

I [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114019/counting-frequency-of-a-sequence-within-a-vector/22578247#22578247) the following:

> [image: answerer asking for code]

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you're asking. Are you saying you just want to request code in an answer? Or that you want to leave contact details in addition to your perfectly fine answer? In any case, I think the answer here is "no". If you want to leave contact details, leave them in your profile.

Comment: @Bart I've seen some answers, in which the person posts his/her email id in the question or answer...so i just want to know is it good practice for stack exchange?

Comment: No, it's not and should probably be removed. Could you link to a particular example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114019/counting-frequency-of-a-sequence-within-a-vector/22578247#22578247 here I see, about which I'm asking.

Comment: Oh dear. That is one *bad* "answer". And no, keep email IDs (actually email addresses) out of posts.

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks buddy, I'll keep in mind.

Comment: Also related: [Should (real) e-mail-addresses be forbidden in questions/answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148394/223030)

Comment: (As an aside, @i.n.e.f: please don't abuse formatting [like you did in the edit of this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/226420/revisions). That suggestion should not have been accepted. I see you're doing it on other sites too. Please use `\`code\`` for code only.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot give your emails inside the Answer. Answer must be

1. For the very specific question and to the point
2. Helpfull for the asker as well as the Community.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

But your email address would only be able to help the asker even if he agrees to send the code to you on your email address.

However, if you really want to send your email address to the asker to work on his code. You can do that inside the comments area, to ask for the code.

Comments is the place generally meant for such items. Whenever you need to ask for more information about the post, such as more clear answer or to ask for some more code inside the question. You can comment at his post and ask for the thing. If you want to contribute something, you can either make it clear inside the comments or edit the post itself.

So, in general, if you want to send your email address to the asker and ask for his code to work on. Use the comments area, and provide your email address there.

In the answers space, you can only answer the question. Leaving away everything that is not related to the question and that would not be helpfull for the community.

### Edit -- After the edit of Arjan

Well this thing is really not allowed on the Stack Overflow.

> Can anyone do this for me?

Is generally a work of a Freelance website, where people would like to send you codes to get money or whatsoever the deal is.

But here, people ask

1. to get help
2. to help
3. to seek help

#### to get help

When an asker is asking a question, he wants to get help from the community. So he provides what he has, and asks the community to better guide him in the task. For example I would like to ask this:

> Hi guys, I was trying to get an output by a variable, but I can't
>   figure it out.
>
> I am using this code:
>
> ```
> int main () {
>   int vrbl = 0;
>   cout << vrbl;
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> I am using C++ to write the program. The problem is it gives me 0 as
>   the output. I can't figure it out. Please help!

#### to help

Now some user might want to come and see my code, after having a look, he would come to the point. That the value inside the variable is 0. I am not getting the value from user or anything like that, so he would ask me to add this one line in my code:

```
cin >> vrbl;
```

After this, the code would work. And I would get the value and then print it on the screen.

#### to seek help

After some time, someone else might have the same problem. And he would not getting the point either, so he searchs and comes to the question. He would find the question (with same criteria) and would have a look at the answer. His problem would get solved too.

### That's how it works here

That's how it works here. You help not only yourself (or the asker) but whole of the community.

Working on emails wouldn't be this. And somehow, it might get flagged as a Spam.

Comment: (Sorry, my edit of the question partly affected your answer. Or maybe not, as it's quite generic and to the point; I wouldn't worry about it.)

Comment: No wonder brother, I will edit the answer :)